# Rails is using wrong version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rubymine

```
➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2014-01-28 patchlevel 376) [i686-darwin15.0.0]

➜  ~  rails -v
Rails 2.3.18

➜  ~  gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.17
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin15.0.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/reboot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86-darwin-15
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374
 - /Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
```

But when I am running my code on IDE, I am getting following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- cron_tools (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

So from above error message, it looks like ruby 2.0.0 is being used. I am also not able to load the files due to some reason.

How can I tell Rails to use Ruby 1.8.7.

I have already done `rvm --default use 1.8.7`

Here is my path

```
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin:/Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@global/bin:/Users/reboot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin:/Users/reboot/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin


➜  ~  which ruby
/Users/reboot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby


➜  ~  which rails
/Users/reboot/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/rails
```

Comment: You should have a .rvmrc file in the rails root folder specifying the ruby version.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I have `ruby-version` file in rails root folder.

Comment: @Reboot do you mean `.ruby-version` (the leading dot is important), and what are the contents of the file? And by *rails root folder* do you mean the root folder of your rails project? Do you also have a `.ruby-gemset` file and, if so, what are its contents?

Comment: @Reboot: Hav you ever installed any other version of ruby and rails in the same machine

Comment: @Vinay Ruby 2.0.0 come installed in my Mac, which is system ruby.

Comment: @lurker sorry yes I meant `.ruby-version`. Inside the file I have 1.8.7

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: @lurker I don't have `gemset`

Comment: My question about where it's located? You have it in your project root folder? And to be totally clear, when you executed `ruby -v` and `rails -v` were you in your project root folder?

Comment: @lurker yes to all your questions.

Comment: Sorry about all the question, but it's necessary for clarification. When you say, *I am running my code on IDE* what exactly do you mean? Running a Rails project usually involves starting up an HTTP server that recognizes the project, and then going to a page defined by the project. Or, running the Rails console from the project's root folder.

Comment: @lurker yes all that can be done in IDE. I am using RubyMines. Same error for running ruby script from console.

Comment: OK reaching a bit here, but when you're in your project root, what does, `whereis ruby` give you?

Comment: @lurker `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100061/discussion-between-reboot-and-lurker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so the problem was when I was using `Rubymine` to run a script it was using Ruby interpret, thats why it was not loading rails environment. Since my script was using `Time.now - 1.month`, where `1.month` comes from Active Support, not Ruby stdlib thats why I was getting the error. I fixed the problem by running the script from terminal

```
./script/runner <filename>
```

and everything worked.

I also had to add this line at the beginning or my `.zshrc` file to fix the problem with Ruby version.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```